# Can I use map on monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, writer

I am new to monads concept and i have to use Writer Monad. Here is my code:

```
newtype WriterLS a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, [String]) } 

instance Monad WriterLS where
  return va = Writer (va, [])
  ma >>= k = let (va, log1) = runWriter ma
                 (vb, log2) = runWriter (k va)
             in  Writer (vb, log1 ++ log2)

instance Applicative WriterLS where
  pure = return
  mf <*> ma = do
    f <- mf
    a <- ma
    return (f a)       

instance Functor WriterLS where              
  fmap f ma = pure f <*> ma 

tell :: String -> WriterLS () 
tell log = Writer ((), [log])

logIncrement :: Int  -> WriterLS Int
logIncrement x = do
                  tell ("Increment:" ++ show x)
                  return (x+1)

logIncrementN :: Int -> Int -> WriterLS Int
logIncrementN x n =    if (n == 1 ) then logIncrement x 
                       else 
                          do
                            y <- logIncrement x
                            logIncrementN y (n-1)

isPos :: Int -> WriterLS Bool
isPos x = if (x>= 0) then (Writer (True, ["poz"])) else (Writer (False, ["neg"]))                           

mapWriterLS :: (a -> WriterLS b) -> [a] -> WriterLS [b]
mapWriterLS f xs = undefined
```

Now, I want to apply map on `WriterLS` in function `mapWriterLS` which is undefined for now. If i call the function `isPos` like `map runWriter $ map isPos [1,-2,3]` it will display the output:

```
[(True,["poz"]),(False,["neg"]),(True,["poz")]
```

When i call `runWriter & mapWriterLS isPos [1,-2,3]` I need the output:

```
([True, False, True], ["poz","neg","poz"]).
```

Comment: If it is a list, yes, but you can use `fmap`, since all `Monad`s are `Functor`s, a monad should always offer an `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

Comment: Note that when defining `mapWriterLS`, `map f :: [a] -> [WriterLS b]`, so really all you need to do is add a function with the type `[WriterLS b] -> WriterLS [b]`.

Comment: ok,thank you. But i am a begginer and i try to figure out how these functions work. how can i define the function mapWriterLS in order to display the expected output? i tried like `mapWriterLS f xs = map f xs `but it's not working.

Comment: @OtiliaDomnea: what are `f` and `xs` here?

Comment: f is the function that i want to apply and xs is the array. mapWriterLS willl be called like this: `runWriter & mapWriterLS isPos [1,-2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

Given an action

```hs
foo :: Int -> WriterLS Bool
foo x
  | x >= 0 = tell "poz" >> return True
  | otherwise = tell "neg" >> return False
```

you can do `runWriter (Writer (1, []) >>= foo)` to get `(True,["poz"])`. But it looks nicer to say `runWriter (return 1 >>= foo)`, since you made `return` into the helper function that abstracts out the details about the written list.

A next step could be to write an action

```hs
foos :: [Int] -> WriterLS [Bool]
foos [] = pure []
foos (x:xs) = do
  b <- foo x
  bs <- foos xs
  return (b:bs)
```

where you can do `runWriter (pure [1,-2,3] >>= foos)` and get

```
([True,False,True],["poz","neg","poz"])
```

Then you've achieved your result in a more concrete way, but you haven't generalised the recursion part of `foos` into some map-like function as you want. I'd think this is easier once you are familiar with the kind of recursion going on.

As Willem hints about, when you say "map", you probably want to have a look at `fmap`, since `WriterLS` is a `Functor`, which is a mathy way of saying that it's mappable in the sense you're aiming for. And as chepner hints about, if you open GHCi and type `:t fmap foo` you get:

```
λ> :t fmap foo
fmap foo :: Functor f => f Int -> f (WriterLS Bool)
fmap foo :: [Int] -> [WriterLS Bool] -- when f = []
```

which is pretty close to but not quite the same as `[Int] -> WriterLS [Bool]`. You could then [ask Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?=&hoogle=Monad%20m%20%3D%3E%20%5Bm%20a%5D%20-%3E%20m%20%5Ba%5D%20package%3Abase&scope=) for something that resembles the missing piece, `Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`.